# $f(x)=2x-e^x<0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

The question is quite simple, but I'm finding some trouble doing it...

***Prove that the function $f(x)=2x-e^x$ is negative, i.e., $f(x)<0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.***

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Find the maximum and show that it's negative.

Comment: Have you tried finding the maximum?

Comment: Oh guys, thank you. That must work. Sorry for such a stupid question...

Comment: There is no stupid questions ! Answers can be !

Comment: There are no stupid questions, only poorly asked ones that break rules.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=2x-\exp(x)$ then we get $$f'(x)=2-\exp(x),$$$$f''(x)=-\exp(x)<0$$
The only solution of $f'(x)=0$ is $x=\ln(2)$ and $$f(\ln(2))=2(\ln(2)-1)<0$$ thus our inequality is proven.

Answer (score 2):

It is a convexity inequality. Since $f(x)=e^x$ is convex, its graphics lies above the graphics of the tangent line through $(\log 2,2)$, i.e.:
$$ e^x \geq 2(x-\log 2)+2 = 2x + 2(1-\log 2) > 2x.$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the above is 
$$2-e^x$$
The derivative is 0 when $x=\ln(2)$
This means the maximum is $2 \cdot (\ln(2)-1)$

However sense $x \lt 0$ the maximum is now at $x=0$, which is $-1$

This is a sketch you can fill this in with monotone properties of the functions involved. Or you could use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: The derivative being $0$ doesn't automatically imply the point is a maximum - it is only a necessary condition. You need to prove $f''(x_0)<0$ or use first derivative test for a sufficient condition.

Comment: @user26486 Of course, but that wasn't what I argued. The functions are monotone, keep in mind that I said this was a sketch, that's the property you'd use to fill that in.

Answer (score 0):

The function $e^x$ is strictly increasing and $y = e\cdot x$ is a tangent to $y = e^x$ at $x = 1$, so $e^x \geq e\cdot x > 2x$ for positive $x$. For nonpositive $x$: $e^x > 0 \geq 2x$. Finally, $e^x > 2x$

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly true for negative numbers. For non-negative numbers, considering the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, we get $2x-e^x=2x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\dots=-1+x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\dots=-(\frac{x}{2}-1)^2-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\dots<0.$